# Access denied when listing Samba shares

Tags: samba, file-sharing, samba4, ubuntu-20.04

I've installed Samba to share files with Windows 10 machines. The setup works correctly to access individual shares using their path such as `\\myhost\sejf`, but listing shares on `\\myhost` fails with access denied. I tried to investigate various possible options, but with no luck. I have a very similar setup on another machine (Raspbian) and there I have no issues, so I suspect it might be somehow related to the OS on the machine, Ubuntu 20.04.

My samba config (created by an Ansible role, but that doesn't really matter):

```
[global]
  # Server information
  netbios name = MYHOST
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  server string = Fileserver %m


  # Logging
  logging = syslog

  # Authentication
  security = user
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  map to guest = never

  # Name resolution: make sure \\NETBIOS_NAME\ works
  wins support = yes
  local master = yes
  domain master = yes
  preferred master = yes

  # Don't load printers
  load printers = no
  printing = bsd
  printcap name = /dev/null
  disable spoolss = yes

  # Fix for CVE-2017-7494 in Samba versions from 3.5.0 and before 4.6.4
  # https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-7494
  nt pipe support = no

  include = /etc/samba/samba.global.conf


## Shared directories
[sejf]
  path = /srv/sejf
  public = no
  create mode = 0664
  force create mode = 0664
  directory mode = 0775
  force directory mode = 0775
  owner = minidlna
```

and the included files `samba.global.conf`:

```
hide files = /lost+found/
server role = standalone server
max log size = 1000000

protocol = SMB3

valid users = @sambashare
write list = @sambashare
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
browseable = yes
group = sambashare
```

I tried to force the protocol with `protocol = SMB3`, but I get the same error with and without it.

Then I tried to list the shares with `smbclient` and I got this strange error:

```
% smbclient -L //myhost/ -U guest
Unable to initialize messaging context
Enter WORKGROUP\guest's password:

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
smb1cli_req_writev_submit: called for dialect[SMB3_11] server[192.168.49.105]
Error returning browse list: NT_STATUS_REVISION_MISMATCH
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.
smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available
```

I also get the error `Failed to connect with SMB1 -- no workgroup available` for the other server where browsing works, so it's apparently unrelated to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the same [ansible role](https://github.com/bertvv/ansible-role-samba/) to manage my samba shares, and I was having the same problem. I think what you're running into is caused by the CVE mitigation

```
  nt pipe support = no
```

Obviously the RCE is problematic, but the version check in the ansible role is broken- I was running 4.13 and it was still including the mitigation. Manually disabling it in my config with

```
samba_mitigate_cve_2017_7494: false
```

fixed things for me.

Comment: Thank you! The incorrect version comparison seem to be fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/vladgh/ansible-collection-vladgh-samba/commit/f214bd92344d89b9a3301bae1d5a04bf738b87b9).